# Should all programmers come to office everyday?

Tags: software-industry

I am a fresh CS graduate. I would like to found a small startup. I hold a small office and want to hire the first 3 programmers. But I have no team work background at all, as it is my first job experience.
Hence why I have the following questions:

Should all programmers be obligated to come to office everyday and work 8 hours there?

Should I check up on them  along the day and ask what they do every few hours?

Should we define a (gantt) chart with day/week/month scope and  ask for results in every scope's goals?

Comment: Remote teams have pros and cons, but keep in mind creating and managing a remote team is far more work for the entrepreneur. For more insight into hiring, running and working as a remote team, take a look at https://zapier.com/learn/remote-work/

Comment: you need to buy the hardware and desktop is probably better most 99% of developers don't *need* a laptop

Comment: I feel like you're focusing on all of the wrong problems. For a startup, you should care about what market need your product will satisfy. Then how to create that product. Decisions like what operating system should I use? Desktop vs laptop? are all very small in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: don't bug devs multiple times a day with "are we there yet". don't leave them unattented for weeks either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remote work is great, but until you learn some management skills (no offense) it might be better to all work in the same place. It makes communication much easier.

Please don't try to nickle and dime your potential new employees. Doing a startup is hard enough already, and if you're cutting back on obvious essentials it can easily send the signal that "management doesn't care about you."

Starting a company with no work or management experience is hard enough as it is. Since you're just starting out, don't mess with the tried-and-true strategy.